# Are my files on an ext4 filesystem recoverable after removing the logical volume the filesystem was inside of?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, lvm, ext4, data-corruption

Scenario:
The other day I was trying to "unmount" some logical volumes so that I could close the LUKS partition they were inside. I accidentally uses **lvremove** thinking that was the right command to use; after I realized it was not I restored my LVM configuration with the backup it created right before **lvremove**.

---

Setup:
I have a single SSD with a single LUKS partition, inside of that is an LVM partition with three logical volumes for swap, root, and home. Root and home are ext4 filesystems. So *SSD(LUKS(LVM(swap,root(ext4),home(ext4))))*

---

Conclusion:
I have determined that the metadata describing my ext4 filesystem has been corrupted. I know this because I have tried to repair it using
`e2fsck -f /dev/ubuntu/home`

I have tried to repair it using backup superblocks
`e2fsck -f -b 12345 /dev/ubuntu-vg/home`

I have used `TestDisk` to try to repair it

I have tried using `extundelete` (it can't find the superblocks)

I have even looked at the raw hex using
`xxd -a /dev/ubuntu-vg/home | less`
and compared it to a working ext4 filesystem

---

Questions:
Is it possible to recover the files using some kind of "deep scan"?
Is this a known problem with LVM and SSDs or is it an anomaly?
When LVM deallocated the memory blocks on the SSD did a TRIM operation or "wear leveling" occur corrupting the data?

Comment: You should `dd` the whole disk to an image (best after unlocking LUKS) and then run `photorec` and/or similar tools on the unencrypted image.  Running `e2fsck` (before making a backup image) usually isn't a good idea though, as it might actually have overwritten some data that was recoverable before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of reading-up on using logical volumes. I ran across this advice from [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM#Remove_logical_volume):

> "Warning: Before you remove a logical volume, make sure to move all
>   data that you want to keep somewhere else; otherwise, it will be
>   lost!"

Based on that, it would appear that your files are "*lost*". Of course, that doesn't mean that there isn't another person out-there somewhere who may have the knowledge concerning how to recover your lost files.